# Fix messed up themes in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, themes, customization, appearance

I recently updated to Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2 and lots of the themes I have look messed up. They either have black backgrounds where it should be white or the text becomes white to match the backgrounds, making it illegible. As you can see in the screenshots, this varies from theme to theme. Is this a problem with the themes or a problem with the Beta and is there anyway to fix this?

[image: white backgrounds become black][image: text changes to match the background]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit these files manually in the ~/.themes directory.  I would find a working 3.4 theme like Axiom, and compare where things have gone afoul.  I've actually cut the entire apps section of Axiom and placed it in another theme's app section, and worked like a charm to remove the cluttered icon effect that's being seen a lot by 3.2 themes on 3.4

Comment: Do you know which files I should fix? I'm not sure while file is associated with what. Which should I fix to fix the problem with the text and black boxes?

Comment: It would be a GTK theme, so any of the GTK3 themes at Gnome Eye Candy.... Sorry Axiom is a Shell theme.  It would the gtk.css file in the gtk-3.0 directory of the theme.  That's the one that has all the colors for the widgets.  One that works well is malys-unisex.  You could get any missing values from that.